# What makes a function static?

Tags: java, static

Specifically using Java. What makes a function static? what does that mean? How should you choose to make the function static or not?

My while loop is broken because "non-static method hasPrecedence(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: This may help answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods

Comment: There are a few other links in the related sidebar that may help you.

Comment: It means that the `static` keyword was specified on the method definition.  The `main` method, eg, must always be `static`.

Answer (score 2):

A static method is called outside of a specific instance of a class.  For example, in the Java library, the `Math.sqrt()` function is not associated with a particular object.

In contrast, non-static methods must be called with a specific object.  For example, a `toUpperCase()` method is defined for String objects:

```
String str = "Hello World.";
String upperStr = str.toUpperCase();
System.out.println(upperStr);
```

Notice that instead of calling `String.toUpperCase()` I used `str.toUpperCase()`.

---

A static method is called *outside* of any specific object.  A non-static method is called *with* a specific object to operate on.

Answer (score 0):

A function is static if there is only one shared among all instances of a class.  Generally, a static function is used for "utility" work.  By this I mean, the function does some work for you that does not/should not require making an instance of the class.  A static function therefore does not make use of or have access to instance variables or instance methods.